# How to change appearance of the state type drop down when disabled mode

Tags: html, css, dropdownbox

[image]We have two drop downs. Based on the first dropdown event changed the second drop down values are getting populated.

How to change appearance of the 2nd type drop down such that it should be different for both enabled and disabled state?

In both drop down they look like  enabled but until we select the country the states not loaded any way .. The `select` CSS was behaving as excepted in IE but not in Chrome. It was looking as enabled in Chrome.

//***********//

```
button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

When I removed the Color inherit from boot strap It makes the difference.How to override the style sheet which effecs the color to the state dropdown in the customized CSS
```

```html
<div class="item1" id="countries">
    <div class="selectbox">
        <select data-bind="options: Countries, 
        optionsText: $data, 
        optionsValue: $data, 
        value: SelectedCountry, 
        event: { change: $parent.CountryActionChanged }">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item2" id="states">
    <div class="selectbox">
        <select data-bind="options: States, 
        optionsText: 'Name', 
        optionsValue: 'Id',
        value: SelectedStateType, 
        event: { change: $parent.StateActionChanged },
        enable: $parent.IsStateType"
        >
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not look like a knockout question to me. Just use CSS to style them?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided a full repro. When I tried to stub out the things you omitted, I ran in to various problems. So I've decided to tell you how you could do things slightly different, in a way that will *also* solve the `enable` binding issue. Here it is:

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  
  self.countries = [
    { name: "US", states: ["NY", "CA", "etc"] },
    { name: "Monaco", states: [] },
    { name: "Vatican", states: [] }
    // etc
  ];
  
  self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
  self.selectedState = ko.observable();  
  
  self.availableStates = ko.computed(function() {
    if (!!self.selectedCountry()) {
      return self.selectedCountry().states;
    }
    return [];
  });
  
  self.selectedCountryHasStates = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.availableStates().length > 0;
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```css
select { min-width: 15em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class="item1" id="countries">
    <div class="selectbox">
        <select data-bind="
            options: countries, 
            optionsText: 'name',
            value: selectedCountry">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item2" id="states">
    <div class="selectbox">
        <select data-bind="
            options: availableStates, 
            value: selectedState, 
            enable: selectedCountryHasStates">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Things to note:

- Don't use the `event` binding unless you *really, really* have to. Instead, use `computed` functions so your view models change dynamically based on the selections made by users.
- (Subjective) Reserve PascalCase for constructor functions, and use camelCase for members and variables.
- Base the `enable` status on whether there are states or not. Do this in a seperate `computed` so you can unit test its logic.
- Try to bind dropdowns to complex object (e.g. `countries` themselves), this makes your view models use the OO features of constructor functions / javascript in a way that makes your code a lot more readable. It also slims down your `data-bind` attributes a lot.